# $\lim_{n\to\infty} \sup_{t \in \mathbb{R}} |F_n(t)+F_n((-t)-)-1|=0$ for i.i.d. symmetric $(X_n)_{n \ge 0}$

Tags: probability-theory

> Let $(X_n)_{n \ge 1}$ be i.i.d. and symmetric with respect to $0$ and let $F_1,F_2, \dots $ be their respective CDF. Show that:
>
> $\lim_{n\to\infty} \sup_{t \in \mathbb{R}} |F_n(t)+F_n((-t)-)-1|=0$

[$F_n(t)=\sum_{i=1}^n \mathrm{1}_{(-\infty,t]}(X_i)$ is the empirical distribution function.]

What I have tried so far:

With symmetry, we can write

$F_n((-t)-)=1-F_n(t-)$

So, now, our problem is to show that:

> $\lim_{n\to\infty} \sup_{t \in \mathbb{R}} |F_n(t)-F_n(t-)|=0$.

Let $Y_n(t)=1_{(-\infty,t]}(X_n)$ and $Z_n(t)=1_{(-\infty,t)}(X_n)$.

Let $F(t-)= \lim_{s \rightarrow t} F(s)$ and $F_n(t-)= \lim_{s \rightarrow t} F_n(s)$.

Then, we have $\mathbb{E} [Y_n(t)]=\mathbb{P} [X_n \le t] =F(t)$ and $\mathbb{E} [Z_n(t)]=\mathbb{P} [X_n < t] =F(t-)$.

So, with LLN, we have:

$F_n(t)=\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i(t) \rightarrow F(t)$

and

$F_n(t-)=\sum_{i=1}^n Z_i(t) \rightarrow F(t-)$.

Combining these, we get

$|F_n(t)-F_n(t-)| \rightarrow |F(t)-F(t-)|=|\mathbb{P}[X_n=t]| = 0$ which shows our problem.

Could it be done like that? I am grateful for any help. Thank you very much.

Comment: I don't understand the statement.  There are 2 left parentheses and 3 right ones in the title and in the displayed equation.  And I don't understand the notation $F_n(-t)-$.  Does it mean to use the càdlàg  version of $F_n(-t)$ ? And I don't understand why you say $F_n((-t)-) = F_n(t-)$.  Isn't $F_n$ the *empirical* CDF, not guaranteed to exacly mirror the theoretical symmetry of the *theoretical* distribution?

Comment: There was a typo in the title (and in the problem), I fixed it now, sorry. What I want to show is $\lim_{t\to\infty} \sup_{t \in \mathbb{R}} |F_n(t)+F_n((-t)-)-1|=0$. So, we are looking at $F_n((-t)-)$.

And for you second opposition: I don't understand your question. Where did I say that $F_n((-t)-)=F_n(t-)$?. I used symmetry to get 
$F_n((-t)-)=1-F_n(t-)$.

Comment: Oh. I mistyped.  What does $(−t)−$ mean?  And how do you use symmetry to show $F_n((-t)-) = 1-F_n(t-))$ ?  Symmetry of *what*?

Comment: I did it like that (but I am not sure if I am allowed to do so, that's why I am asking here): https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/264087/definition-of-symmetric-random-variable-in-terms-of-distribution-function

Comment: The thing that is symmetric in your problem, I think, is the underlying theoretical distribution of the $X_i$, not  the empirical measures $F_n$. In the case $n=1$, for example, if $F_1(t)$ were forced to be symmetric as you wish, values of $X_1\ne 0$ would be impossible.

Comment: Hmm, yes, I don't know if I can use symmetry for $F_n$. However, couldn't I use the same arguments to show that $|F_n(t)+F_n((-t)-)-1| \rightarrow |F(t)+F((-t)-)-1|$ and then use symmetry for the $F$? So, $|F(t)+F((-t)-)-1|=|F(t)+1-F(t-)-1|=|F(t)-F(t-)|$?

Comment: $$F_n((-t)-)=\mathbb P(X_n<-t)=\mathbb P(-X_n>t)=1-\mathbb P(X_n\leq t)=1-F_n(t).$$
So $|F_n(t)+F_n((-t)-)-1|=|F_n(t)+1-F_n(t)-1|=0$ for any $t$.

Comment: Is it really possible to this? >$F_n((-t)-)=\mathbb{P}(X_n < -t)$? Don't we have to pay attention to the limit?

Comment: $F_n(-t)=\mathbb P(X_n\leq -t)$ and $F_n((-t)-)=\mathbb P(X_n < -t)$ is left limit.

Comment: Ok, so if I get this right, I don't have to define $Y_n$ and $Z_n$ as above to prove the statement? $\lim_{n\to\infty} \sup_{t \in \mathbb{R}} |F_n(t)+F_n((-t)-)-1|=\lim_{n\to\infty} \sup_{t \in \mathbb{R}} |F_n(t)+1-F_n(t)-1|=0$?

Comment: Also, I just realised that there was another typo. The statement that has to be shown is $\lim_{n\to\infty} \sup_{t \in \mathbb{R}} |F_n(t)+F_n((-t)-)-1|=0$, the limit goes from $n \rightarrow \infty$. I am sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I think the original problem really is:  Let $F_n$ be the empirical cdf of $X_1,\ldots,X_n$, and let $G_n$ be the empirical cdf of  $-X_1, \ldots, -X_n$.  At all points of continuity of $F_n$ and $G_n$ we have $G_n(x) = 1-F_n(-x)$ and $F_n(t)-G_n(t) = F_n(t)+F_n(-t)-1$.  What is required is to show that, with probability $1$, $\sup_t|F_n(t)-G_n(t)|\to 0$.

Write $|F_n(t)-G_n(t)| = |(F_n(t)-F(t)) - (G_n(t) - G(t))|\le |F_n(t)-F(t)| + |G_n(t)-G(t)|$, where $F$ is the theoretical distribution function for the law of $X_n$ and $G$ the theoretical distribution function for the law of $-X_n$. (So $G(t) = 1-F(-t)$ at all continuity points.)  But the distribution of the $X_i$ is symmetric, so $G(t) = F(t)$ for all $t$.

By Glivenko-Cantelli we know $\sup_t |F_n - F|$ converges to $0$ with probability $1$.  And also that $\sup_t|G_n-G|$ does too.  This implies $$\sup_t|F_n-G_n| \le \sup_t |F_n-F| + \sup_t |G_n-G| \to 0$$ as well.

The use of the unexplained notation $(-t)-$ did not help.

Comment: Thank you ver much for that answer. However, I don't understand this step: $|F_n(t)-G_n(t)| = |(F_n(t)-F(t)) - (G_n(t) - G(t))|$. This would mean that $-F(t)+G(t)=0$, but how can this be?

Comment: Oh, I forgot to mention:  since the $X_i$ are symmetric, the distribution of $X_i$ is the same as that of $-X_i$.  That is to say, $G=F$.  Just as you said.

Comment: Ah, right. But then, why do we have to split the sum like that? With $G=F$, shouldn't $|F_n(t)-G_n(t)|=0$? Also, I too don't really now what the notation $(-t)-$ means, but I think it is the limit from the left hand side.

Comment: The theoretical distribution is symmetric but the samples drawn from it are probably not.  So $F(t)=G(t)$ holds for all $t$ but $F_n(t)$ might well differ from $G_n(t)$.  For instance, suppose your first two sample $X$ values were $X_1= 1$ and $X_2 = -1.5$.  Then $F_2(t) $ has discontinuities at $t=-1.5$ and $1$, but $G_2(t)$ has discontinuities at $t=-1$ and $1.5$.  Graph two two curves.  The $F_n$ and $G_n$ curves are different.

Comment: I see, thank you ver much for your help!